# Sending HTML mail from PHP not working as expected

Tags: php, html, email

I'm having a weird issue with my HTML when sending from PHP. Hyperlinks are nos showed as they should. This is how it renders on my email client:

[Link to image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2939835/temp/Inbox%20%287727%20messages%29.jpg)

As you can see, there are 2 variables sending strings to the email body:

```
    $texto_msg = 'HOLA <a href="http://vendoan.com">ANCHOR</a>';
    $url_anuncio = 'Sal bien!!: <a href="'.get_permalink($post_tmp).'">Título: '.get_the_title($post_tmp).'</a>';


    $e_subject = __('Alguien se ha interesado por tu anuncio en VendoAndroid','jigowatt');

    // Advanced Configuration Option.
    // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
    // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

    $msg  = __('¡Hola! Un usuario de VendoAndroid se ha interesado en tu anuncio:'). PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    //$msg .= __('<a href="'.get_permalink($post_tmp).'">Título: '.get_the_title($post_tmp).'</a>') . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= __($texto_msg) . PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= __($url_anuncio) . PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= implode(PHP_EOL, $comments) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n";
    $msg .= 'Mensaje enviado desde <a href="http://vendoandroid.com" ><strong>VendoAndroid.com</strong></a>';

    $msg = wordwrap( $msg, 70 );
```

I don't understand why the first link works well and not the second one.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Update:

@Joachim Isaksson, this is the original source:

```
<p>Â¡Hola! Un usuario de VendoAndroid se ha interesado en tu anuncio:</p>
<p>TÃ­tulo: <strong>Puto Firefox jodio</strong><br />
<a href="http://vendoandroid.com/mis-anuncios/"><strong>Ã¡rea de<br />
usuario.</strong></a><br />
Puedes ver, editar o eliminar tu anuncios accediendo a tu <a<br />
href="http://vendoandroid.com/mis-anuncios/"><strong>Ã¡rea de<br />
usuario.</strong></a><br />
```

Comment: what's with the __()   ???

Comment: Please use "view source" and either inspect the line with the dysfunctional href tag yourself or add it to your question. I suspect `get_permalink()` may return something unexpected.

Comment: Should have know it was wordpress...bleh.

Comment: Question updated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. There's some kind of problem with Wordpress core.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/make_clickable

Trying to fix it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The __($text) function might returns the translated $text if one is found in the translation table. You shouldn't mix HTML and raw text while using it.

Try :

```
$url_anuncio = __("Sal bien!!:").' <a href="'.get_permalink($post_tmp).'"> '.__("Título: ").get_the_title($post_tmp)."</a>";
```

and then :

```
$msg .= $url_anuncio . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Here is the Localization documentation about WP : http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology

Comment: Thank you, but still the same result. It's weird, because whatever goes in $comments get proper HTML formatting.

       $msg .= implode(PHP_EOL, $comments) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;